# get localhost file in mac osx 10.8

Tags: localhost, osx-mountain-lion, xcode4.4

Mac osx 10.6.8 to Mac osx 10.8 update, IN xcode4.4 am try to get the localhost xml file this error(**You don't have permission to access localhost/~users/sample.xml on this server**.)

give me a solution.

Comment: Is your app running in the sandbox?

Answer (score 1):

Friend, try those links:
http://www.coolestguyplanettech.com/downtown/install-and-configure-apache-mysql-php-and-phpmyadmin-osx-108-mountain-lion
http://www.coolestguyplanettech.com/installing-phpmyadmin-on-mac-osx-10-7-lion/

Comment: friend localhost works fine am not access sites directory file